# Is there a name for this type of design?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, encapsulation

So I am writing a game (c#, xna), and was just wondering if there is a name for what I am doing.

This isn't necessarily specific to Game Programming, or my game. But programming and encapsulation in general.

Essentially I have two game objects, one (Chute) is dependent on the data of another (the list of Blueprints in BlueprintManager). I don't want to expose the BlueprintManagers list of Blueprints to the outside world. However Chute needs to know them to operate.

So instead of exposing the list of Blueprints, I created a method in BlueprintManager which accepts a Chute, and in that method "gives" it's Blueprints to the Chute.

Now I am wondering if this is an effective way to maintain the encapsulation of my data. Also I am wondering if there is a name for this type of method/design. Any best practices for this?

This code is in BlueprintManager which has the list of Blueprints which Chute needs.

```
        public void GiveChuteBlueprints(Chute chute)
        {
            chute.AcceptBlueprints(this._acitveBlueprints);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to me.

Comment: Thanks, will research this pattern!